# Why did the British people switch from the Celtic language to Old English?

Tags: england, language

There is a widely held theory that when the Romans left England in the 5th century AD the island was defenceless against Anglo-Saxon invading armies. In the south and east the Britons were defeated in battle and the Anglo-Saxons established their own kingdoms. They brought their Germanic languages with them -Old English- which became dominant in the new kingdoms and ultimately in Britain as a whole. Only Wales and Cornwall were able to retain their Celtic language and culture.

However, a recent history programme on the BBC disputes this theory. They claim there is no evidence of a border between Celtic and Anglo-Saxon speaking regions, nor of battles along such a border in the 5th century. Instead they claim that Wales and Cornwall were regions in the west that were involved in trade with France and Spain. Whereas the south and east of England had contacts around the North Sea with Belgium, Netherlands, Germany, Denmark and Norway. There was trade, and perhaps some migration of settlers, but certainly no conquest by invading Anglo-Saxon armies.

Assuming that the theory of the BBC is correct, why is it that the common people (farmers, fishermen, villagers) in the south and east of England stopped speaking the Celtic language of their ancestors and instead switched to Old English, the language of a relatively small group of newcomers? We can also ask why the Anglo-Saxon newcomers stuck so tightly to their own language that they did not learn any Celtic words or phrases from their British neighbours.

Comment: It would help if you linked to or even named the programme.

Comment: An interesting question, but my first reaction to it is that the best answer is that one of the premises ("that the theory of the BBC is correct") is incorrect, as otherwise the BBC would have it that I'm typing this in Celtic.

Comment: Any proposed *theory* that lacks basic internal consistency, loses the right to be considered as a theory. It is instead a fantasy, as here. We have annals from both the Celtic (Bede) and Anglo-Saxon side (Anglo-Saxon Chronical), as well as substantial archaeological evidence supporting the basic outline of a conflict between Germanic invaders and indigenous Celtic inhabitants n the 300+ years following the Roman withdrawal.  I know not what motivated BBC to broadcast such tripe; I can only inquire as to your confidence that it wasn't rather a late-night paid promotion.

Comment: Nothing personal, but I'm not going to "assume ..." a TV show ".. is correct." That's not the way to get at truth. I can also prove all kinds of utterly wrong mathematical "facts", if you let me [divide by zero](https://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0by0.html).

Comment: It was a one hour long television programme about Britain in the 5th century. The BBC takes their history programmes very seriously. They consult experts from English universities. The claim is that while there are indeed documents about battles between Britons and Anglo-Saxons, modern archeological research does not support it. The settlement of Anglo-Saxons in England was to a large degree peaceful.

Comment: It's not really answerable without knowing the status of the Brythonic languages in Britain at the time. Roman administration ends in 410 ad after 367 years of presence. What percentage of the population is bilingual or only speaks a Latin derivative? A group of Frisians were relocated to somewhere around Kent during the 3rd century (a couple of centuries before the Anglo-Saxons show up), did they continue to speak Frisian or adopt the local Brythonic or Latin?

Comment: Without some indication as to what show it is difficult for anyone to observe and challenge the claims therein.  I would refrain from defining this as the BBC's theory.  It is far more likely that this is someone else's theory that they have given air time to.  That source has probably published their theory and there may be reviews and critiques of it.

Comment: The change in language probably happened later than the 5th century.  As I remember by about 500, the start of the 6th century, there were thousands of Germanic graves along the east coast, and hundreds or thousands of memorial stones  inscribed in latin along the west coast, and very littlea rchaelogical evidence of the hundreds of thousands of other people who should have been alive at any one moment then. There is no evicence that the Germanics conquered or settled more than a small part of post Roman Britain by AD 500.  Cotinued.

Comment: Continued.  But the Germanics coulquerd almost all of Southern England, exept Cornawlland Wales, and the eastern edge of northern England, by about 597, the beginning of the misssion to convert the Angles.  And no doubt the majority of the population in those regions spoke some type of British languague and gradually over many centuries adopted the English language and English culture to assimilate and stop being oppressed.  Ezrly English laws mention a separate class of "Welsh" who should have still spoken some form of Britsh.

Comment: Never trust the BBC!